# Continuity of poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Is a Poisson process continuous in probability? Or more generally, when is a counting process continuous in probability?

Answer (score 3):

More generally, if $N=\{N_t,t\ge 0\}$ is a counting process with $N_0=0$, $T_n=\inf\{t>0: N_t\ge n\}$ is the $n$-th time of jumps of $N$, then $N$ is continuous in probability if and only if the distribution functions, $\{F_{T_n}(x)=\mathsf{P}(T_n\le x),n\ge 1\}$, all are continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Poisson process is continuous in probability. A simple way to check this is to visualize the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. In fact, any [Levy process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process) is continuous in probability. (Note that this is very different from being almost surely continuous, which is kind of counter intuitive!)

Here is an intuition for the Poisson process: Suppose that $s \to t$, from below. The probability that there is an arrival between $s$ and $t$ is going to zero as $s$ get's closer to $t$. So the probability that $X_s$ is not $X_t$ is also going to zero.

You can compute this explicitly for the Poisson process.

For a general Levy process $X_t$, the stationary increments property means that you only have to argue that as $\delta \to 0$, $X_{\delta} \to 0$ in distribution. Note that convergence in distribution would enough to show that $P ( |X_{\delta}| > \epsilon) \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$, so we will show that in the next paragraphs. (To show it is enough: use a continuous, non-negative test function which is $0$ around $0$, and $1$ on $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : \epsilon > 0\}$ to conclude that if $Z_n \to c$ in distribution, where $c$ is a constant, then $Z_n \to c$ in probability.)

There is hopefully an easier way to show this, but convergence in distribution follows from the Lévy–Khintchine theorem.

Lévy–Khintchine says that some distribution $\mu$ is an infinitely divisible distribution iff it has characteristic function of the form $\hat{\mu}( \xi ) = exp( - \Psi(\xi))$, where $\Psi(\xi)$ is a function you can see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Khintchine_representation

This implies ([using stationary independent increments, and right continuity of Levy process paths](https://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/math7880/S11/Chapters/Ch1.pdf)) that if $X_t$ is a Levy process, then for all $t$, $\hat{X}_t = \exp ( - t \Psi(\xi))$.

(I was a little confused about branches and $n$th roots and stuff -- I think the point is that there are canonical $n$th roots of $\hat{X}_1$, given by $\hat{X}_{1/n}$. Writing $(\hat{X}_1)^{1/n}$ is a little sloppy, since this doesn't uniquely define a function. The point is that $\hat{\mu}_{1/n}$ satisfies the correct equation making it an $n$th root of $\hat{\mu}$. Maybe I'm still missing something... will ask and update.)

This implies that $\hat{ X}_{\delta}  = exp (- \delta \Psi(\xi)) \to 1$ pointwise, which by Levy's continuity theorem implies that $X_{\delta}$ converges to $\delta_0$ in distribution as $\delta \to 0$. As discussed above, this implies that $X_{\delta} \to \delta_0$ in probability.

Overall this shows that $X_{\delta} \to 0$ in probability as $\delta \to 0$. Now, $P ( | X_t - X_s | > \epsilon) = P ( |X_{t - s} | > \epsilon)$ by stationary increments, so the continuity of the Levy process *in probability* follows.